# How to write Unit Test involving checking updates in the database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I have this method that I would like to write a unit test for, but I just do not know how to do so.
I'm using C# and the .NetMaui Framework and SQlite.

This is the method I'd like to test:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// ViewModel gets Intent from OrgansisationViewModel, either Create or Update
        /// Create: New Organisation will be added to the database
        /// Update: existing one will be updatet
        /// </summary>
        [ICommand]
        public async void CreateOrUpdate()
        {
            Model.LastViewDate = DateTime.Now;
            switch (intent)
            {
                case Intent.Create:
                    await _unitOfWork.Organisations.Add(Model);
                    await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrganisationViewModel));
                    break;
                case Intent.Update:
                    _unitOfWork.Organisations.Update(Model);
                    await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OrganisationViewModel));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I want to test if a new entity is being created or if one is being updated depending on the intend. Could I also test if my app will switch to the OrganisationView?

Comment: You **don't**: a test that uses a database is not a "unit test", it's an integration test. While you _can_ use VS/.NET's unit-testing frameworks and libraries for integration tests it isn't recommended (and the maintainers of xUnit are quite religious about that...), as ideally the infrastructure for integration-tests is your own responsibility.

Comment: Use a verifiable mock for the `Add` and `Update` methods, then check that the appropriate stub was called.